# PHP Parser - Find String in HTML

Tags: php, html, parsing

I want to find a string on another website. I have been looking at parsers and I do not know the best way to do it. I looked at an HTML DOM parser but I need just a simple one line output. I just want to get the link "url: 'http://s2.example.com/streams/i23374.mp4?k=12f34588cf171f3bbf3d35da4db43b06'" to a variable.

```
<script>
                flowplayer("player", "http://www.example.com/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf",  {
                    canvas: {
                        backgroundGradient: "none",
                        backgroundColor: "#000000"
                    },
                    clip: {
                        provider: 'lighttpd',
                        url: 'http://s1.example.com/streams/i23374.mp4?k=12f34588cf171f3bbf3d35da4db43b06',
                        scaling: 'fit'
                    },
                    plugins: {
                        lighttpd: {
                            url: 'http://www.example.com/flowplayer.pseudostreaming-3.2.12.swf'
                        }
                    }
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: Look into phpQuery or QueryPath for one-liners. Such a DOM traversal frontends (or plain longwinded DOMDocument) will still just net you the Javascript blob. You'd require a regex and/or JSON/L parser still to *extract* just the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a handy function for grabbing the text from between two delimiters;

```
<?php
function extract_unit($string, $start, $end)
{
    $pos = stripos($string, $start);
    $str = substr($string, $pos);
    $str_two = substr($str, strlen($start));
    $second_pos = stripos($str_two, $end);
    $str_three = substr($str_two, 0, $second_pos);
    $unit = trim($str_three); // remove whitespaces
    return $unit;
}

echo extract_unit($webpageSource, 'flowplayer("player", "', '",  {');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `DOMDocument`:

For getting a link off of an anchor, it's:

```
$dd = new DOMDocument;
@$dd->loadHTMLFile('http://s2.example.com/streams/i23374.mp4?k=12f34588cf171f3bbf3d35da4db43b06');
if($a = $dd->getElementsByTagName('a')){
  foreach($a as $t){
    $links[] = $t->getAttribute('href');
  }
}
```

Now `$links` is an Array with each `href`, or `if(!isset($links))` there are no results.

To get JSON from a script tag:

```
$dd = new DOMDocument;
@$dd->loadHTMLFile('http://s2.example.com/streams/i23374.mp4?k=12f34588cf171f3bbf3d35da4db43b06');
if($s = $dd->getElementsByTagName('script')){
  $c = $dd->sameHTML($s->item(0)));
}
```

Change `item(0)` to the level where the `script` tag is on their page. Now `$c` is a String. So:

```
preg_match_all("/url: '.+'/", $c, $results);
```

`$results` is an Array should contain `url: 'whatever'`.
So:

```
foreach($results as $v){
  $a[] = preg_replace('/url: /', '', $v);
}
```

`$a` is Array of results.

Comment: I am not trying to get info from that website I am trying to extract that link from the source.

Comment: Hold on, I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly RegExp is the best way to parse string, although it's not recommended to handle JSON.

Here's an example(I encoded the string, it's the same as your raw HTML):

```
<?php 
$data = base64_decode("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");

if(preg_match('/clip:\s*\{[\s\S]+url:\s*\'(\S+)\',\s*scaling/', $data, $match) === 1)
echo $match[1];

?>
```

Although it's encoded in JSON, it can't be parsed by PHP's `json_decode` because PHP's JSON format is too strict (attributes should be wrapped in quotes).